# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, web3js-v1.x

When I want to call MyContract's function like:

```
address payable owner = 0x12345.....;
function addHouse(uint _lease,uint _totalRent,uint _tenantNum)public{
            houseInfo[owner].push(House(owner,houseCount,_lease,_totalRent,_tenantNum));
            houseLandlord[houseCount] = owner;
            houseRent[houseCount] = _totalRent;
            houseCount++;
}
```

using the api of (methods.myMethod.send),

```
app.post("/addhouse_success",function(req,res){
    var lease = req.body.lease;
    var totalrent = req.body.totalrent;
    var tenantnum = req.body.tenantnum;
    MyContract.methods.addHouse(lease,totalrent,tenantnum).send({from: address},function(error,transactionHash){
        console.log('in function')
        if(!error){
            console.log('transactionHash:',transactionHash)
            res.send({msg:"ok",hash:transactionHash});
        }else{
            console.log('-------------error-----------')
            console.log(error)
            console.log('-------------error-----------')
        }
    });
})
```

but I get the error when using that api:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ABICoder.formatParam (/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:224:30)
    at /node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:100:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:94:21)
    at /ode_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:439:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:438:8)
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:701:39)
    at Object._executeMethod (/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:720:68)
    at /index.js:102:60
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Is there anyone can help me solve this problem???
The question nagged me for days.
And the web3's version is 1.3.6

Comment: From the stack trace the problems seems to be the parameters. Can you check if they valid integers are passed to the contract?

Comment: Thanks for answering!!  I find the reason is that I forget to add '#' to access the html's input id so that the integer passed to the contract is undefined.....